# Mpir Windows build with --enable-gmpcompat?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpir

Per [mpir documentation](http://www.mpir.org/mpir-2.7.2.pdf), using `--enable-gmpcompat`
 switch when running `./configure` will produce `gmp.lib` and `gmp.h` for compatibility. There is not a single word how to do that in Windows build though. How to do this in the Visual Studio project? I assume the flag does not simply rename the target but does some other stuff behind the scenes.